# Using global variables in pytest

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I am trying to write a test as follows and an ending up getting the following error:

```
def test_retry():
  hits = 0

  def f():
    global hits
    hits += 1
    1 / 0

  with pytest.raises(ZeroDivisionError):
    f()
```

and get the following error:

```
>       hits += 1
E       NameError: name 'hits' is not defined
```

but am curious why this code doesn't work. Does pytest somehow alter the global variables?

I know this can be solved using a list like `hits = [0]`, but i'm trying to understand why the code doesn't work.

I've also tried using `pytest_configure`, and that works too.

Comment: The way you've defined `f()`, it's a sub-function inside of `test_retry()`.  Is that intentional?

Comment: yes - that was intentional. Trying to test retry policy (didn't include the decorator for sanity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `nonlocal` instead. `hits` is not a global variable.

```py
nonlocal hits
```